# intermittent TNS-12533: TNS:illegal ADDRESS parameters

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-xe

I am running a windows XP (SP3) VM in virtualbox, on which I host Oracle XE.

It has been running fine like this for a couple of years, but recently I am seeing some strange problems.

My client software fails, and the log files say :
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

So I log on to the DB, and try running `sqlplus / as sysdba;`

which gives me the following:
`ora-12560 tns protocol adapter error`

So following the debugging steps from several websites, I try this:
`tnsping db`
and the result is :
`TNS-12533: TNS:illegal ADDRESS parameters`

So I decide to test another SID:
`tnsping xe`
which works fine.

As you can see from the tnsnames.ora file, those two SIDs are configured identically.

I've not touched that file in a couple of years and don't intend to do so now.

So I restart the windows machine, and now everything works.

Why did the error message indicate a problem with the file, when upon restart it doesn't complain?

Why would this suddenly stop working?

I checked the alert log and found this:

```
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:CreateThread failed with status: 8
ORA-27301: OS failure message: Not enough storage is available to process this command.
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: ssthrddcr
Process J000 died, see its trace file
kkjcre1p: unable to spawn jobq slave process
```

I've tried wiping some files from the hard disk (there was 1GB free space, which seems like plenty) but it hasn't worked.

Any ideas?

The contents of my tnsnames.ora file include:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = windows-virtual)(PORT = 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
  )
)

DB=
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = windows-virtual)(PORT = 1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SERVER = DEDICATED)
     (SERVICE_NAME = DB)
   )
 )
```

Comment: Your tnsnames file has a syntax error (mismatched parens). Is that a copy/paste problem?

Comment: As for the ORA-27300, I'd look more into memory/swap issues or process limits. (32bit WinXP isn't exactly the ideal server environment for Oracle.)

Comment: @Mat yes thanks, that was a copy/paste which I've corrected in the question.

Comment: @Mat and yes windows is not ideal.  If oracle could be bothered to make a release for OS X I could run it natively.  But it's been running without a problem for 4 years, so I'm trying to understand why it's now broken...

Comment: `CreateThread failed with status: 8` - error 8 is `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`. You could have a slow leak, or simply your dataset growth is making something walk a bit over your available (virtual) memory. As for OS X: you could run a 64bit OS in a VM. I'd go with a Linux distro but I'm _totally_ biased :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try any one or both

1. Try using IP for HOST
2. Also remove `(SERVER = DEDICATED)` row from `tnsname.ora` file.

Comment: Please edit you answer to describe why the OP should try these two methods.